# How can I calculate Stripes Connect payout fee into my transfer

Tags: math, stripe-payments, percentage

What would be the math to calculate out Stripes payout fees (0.25% + $0.25/payout) from each transfer to a Connect account?

FYI - Stripe takes the fee from the total amount of all transfers, but I need to compute it out for each transfer I send.

ex. I want to transfer $100.00 => 10000 cents

1. 10000 cents - 25 cents(1st transfer in a pay period only) = 9975 cents
2. Here's where I get lost/confused - I can't take out 0.25% of 9975 (~25cents) because Stripe will only charge a fee from the remaining amount I send ~9950 cents. So the fee I took (~25) is too high for the amount I sent to payout.

Can anyone help me with the math?

Answer (score 0):

you can look over here for my approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775321/2434784

But some of the tl,dr is yes, you can just use the straight-forward approach above.  Since the fees are currently 0.25%, you will only be off by 0.25%/(1 + 0.25%) - not much of a concern.  Reserve the pessimistic amount, and reconcile each month with Stripe's actual charges.

Comment: Hi Lead. Thanks for the help, I'm going to post some info additional info to see if you have any advice. I'll post it in the thread where you posted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can reach out to Stripe support to clarify the fees https://support.stripe.com/contact.